# Xcode help? - " 'didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation' undeclared " + " Expected ';' before ':' token "

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I am trying to create an application in Xcode that will switch to a new view when the phone is rotated from one orientation to another.

Here is the "switchviewcontroller.h" file code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwitchViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender;

@end
```

---

And here is the "switchviewcontroller.m" file code:

---

```
#import "SwitchViewController.h"
#import "secondview.h"

@implementation SwitchViewController

-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender

// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
       (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    {    
        [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondview" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }

}
```

I get the 2 errors showed in the question, so it doesn't work.

Comment: The code isn't showing up correctly :(

Comment: Note: you could use `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation)` in the if clause of `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` to make the code a little simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the implementation block for `-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender`
 - make it `-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender {}` and try again.

Comment: It now says expected identifier or '(' before '{' token.

Comment: Oh wait now I have got it to run, but not sure if it works though.